# Trigger the setinterval() only if value changed

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code where the `setInterval()` is triggered every 2 sec to update the `var kraken_btc_eur`

However sometimes the variable retrieved from the API does not change. Therefore, to save some serveur processing I would like to avoid the setInterval action to be triggered .

Maybe what I am asking does not make sense, it is just a though for optimisation.

Thank you for your guidance.

```
var kraken_btc_eur_old = 0;

setInterval(function(){

    $.get('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR', function(data){ 

        var kraken_btc_eur = data.result.XXBTZEUR.c[0]; //get the value of 1 bitcoin
        //some logic to change the css if the value increased or decreased
        if (kraken_btc_eur_old > kraken_btc_eur) {

            $(".kraken_btc_eur").css('color', 'red').text(kraken_btc_eur);
        } else {
            $(".kraken_btc_eur").css('color', 'green').text(kraken_btc_eur);                
        }

        kraken_btc_eur_old = kraken_btc_eur; //set the global variable to the value of 1 bitcoin so that in 2 sec it will be checked in the if statement
        $(".kraken_btc_eur").text(kraken_btc_eur); //show the value to the user to the html tag with the corresponding class

    });

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific (maybe through code comments in your posted code) about what should trigger bypassing the next `setInterval` call?

Comment: apparently you cannot know it before you go to the server, so either you need to stop the rendering in case the value of `kraken_btc_eur_old == kraken_btc_eur` or you have to find out what defines a changes to the response from the server side, and maybe use server side push requests

Answer (score 0):

With setInterval, you are using an approach called short-polling. This is when you continuously request data from the server to determine if anything changed.

There are two major alternatives to short-polling. Of these, I believe you are looking for WebSockets, which are essentially Sockets that you can use with JavaScript. WebSockets allow you to pass unformatted data from the client to the server, and vice versa. Using WebSockets, your server would have to keep an open socket to the client, but would only send data to the client if something changed on the server's side.

Of course, this is assuming you are the developer of the API.

If not, you'll have to stick to short polling. You could have an approach where if the value from the API doesn't change for a while, you could decrease the frequency of your short polls - but that would require you to switch from setInterval to setTimeout. In your callback, you could determine what the new timeout will be between the current callback and the next callback.

This approach would look something like the following:

```
setTimeout(function callback(timeout){

  // .. get request here

  if(timeout !== undefined)
  {
    if(kraken_btc_eur == kraken_btc_eur_old)
    {
      timeout = Math.min(10000, timeout + 1000);
    }
    else
    {
      timeout = 2000;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    timeout = 2000;
  }

  setTimeout(callback.bind(window, timeout), timeout);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe kraken api has an etag header not so sure. You can check if the etag is the same with the old etag means the data hasn't change.

Some reference.
http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/etags-revisited/
https://www.infoq.com/articles/etags

If you have the option of setting up a websocket its better. Check https://socket.io/.

Answer (score 0):

You can make few changes in your code

```
var window.kraken_btc_eur_old = 0;

function makeRequest(oldValue) {

   $.get('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR', 
   function(data){ 

       var kraken_btc_eur = data.result.XXBTZEUR.c[0]; 
       if(kraken_btc_eur !== oldValue){

          //get the value of 1 bitcoin
          //some logic to change the css if the value increased or decreased
          if (oldValue > kraken_btc_eur) {
              $(".kraken_btc_eur").css('color', 'red').text(kraken_btc_eur);
          } else {
              $(".kraken_btc_eur").css('color', 'green').text(kraken_btc_eur);                
          }

          window.kraken_btc_eur_old = kraken_btc_eur; 

          //set the global variable to the value of 1 bitcoin so that in 2 sec it will be checked in the if statement

          $(".kraken_btc_eur").text(kraken_btc_eur); //show the value to the user to the html tag with the corresponding class
          }
      });
}


setInterval(makeRequest.bind(null,window.kraken_btc_eur_old), 2000);
```

I have written window.kraken_btc_eur_old just to give you an understanding that it's a global object